# Use of Executor Service

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

Do the threads in executor service run in parallel and are not time sliced when a task is submitted to them? If they don't run in parallel then what's the use of executor service?

Comment: In general, ALL threads in Java can be time sliced.  When any thread is blocked (say on IO) another thread may be substituted to take its place.  A CPU with 4 cores can run 4 processes, but there may be 100 threads "running" at the same time due to being swapped out by IO or time slicing.

Comment: Note:  `ExecutorService` is an _interface_, not an implementation.  If you only knew that something was an ExecutorService, then you would not know how many threads (if any) it used, or how they were scheduled.  In the most common implementations however, if you did not provide a custom `ThreadFactory`, then there would be no reason to think that the threads were scheduled any differently from any other threads in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ExecutorService` is simply an abstraction over performing asynchronous operations. It takes care of managing incoming tasks and spreading them over the available threads.

As for the threads themselves, it depends on the environment, i. e. the machine, os and jvm. If you have a single processor with one core, or if the os doesn't support it, you're not going to do stuff in parallel. However on modern machines you'll definitely experinece parallel execution to some degree. Remember that even if you create threads manually, there's no guarantee that they will be executed in parallel by the operating system.

Comment: So if we normally create 3 threads then they won't run in parallel but if we submit a task to executor service having 3 threads, then these 3 threads will execute the task in parallel right?

Comment: No, there's no "magic" to an `ExecutorService` that will make tasks run in parallel. The existing implementations use the same threads that you can create on your own. The difference is that using an `ExecutorService` is more convinient than creating threads on your own.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the reply. I have one more question, Fork and join is a specialized version of executor service which enables the threads to execute the tasks in parallel right?

Comment: I think we're slightly misunderstanding each other. Using threads, either explicitly or through an `ExecutorService`, does enable you to run tasks in parallel, but there's no guarantee that every thread will run perfectly in parallel to others (i. e. they can, and most likely will, be timesliced). `ForkJoinPool` is just a convienience class for running `ForkJoinTask`. Again, it doesn't make threads "more parallel" than they can be.

Comment: I actually asked about fork and join because in c# we have task parallel library which enables threads to executes the task perfectly in parallel i guess. So in java is there a way to perfectly run threads in parallel or can they be only time sliced?

Comment: `in c# we have task parallel library which enables threads to executes the task perfectly in parallel` - your assumptions are incorrect, TPL is actually similar to an `ExecutorService`. Both will try to maximise the number of tasks run in paralell, but they use system level threads, so they can't guarantee perfect parallelism. In fact, you can't have perfectly parallel execution if you're running more threads than you have processors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118759/discussion-between-xylene23-and-pablochan).

Answer (score 1):

From Java docs:

> An Executor that provides methods to manage termination and methods that can produce a Future for tracking progress of one or more asynchronous tasks.

Generally, **ALL** Callables submitted to an `ExecutorService` will always be run parallel to the main thread. As for submitted tasks in an `ExecutorService`, they can be parallel depending on how many threads are specified to run in the service.

If you are using an executor service that only has 1 `Thread`, then no matter how many tasks you submit, only one will be run at any given time **on that executor service**.

If you have an executor service that uses 5 `Threads`, then at most 5 submitted tasks will be running in parallel to each other.

Here's a sample code:

```
public class ExecutorServiceTest {
public static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Submitting!");

    service.submit(new PrintCallable("Callable 1"));
    service.submit(new PrintCallable("Callable 2"));
    service.submit(new PrintCallable("Callable 3"));
    service.submit(new PrintCallable("Callable 4"));
    service.submit(new PrintCallable("Callable 5"));

    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("Done!");
}

private static class PrintCallable implements Callable<Void> {

    private final String toPrint;

    private PrintCallable(String toPrint) {
        this.toPrint = toPrint;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println(toPrint);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Running that code will print a "Callable x" in an interweaving manner.

Note: I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find anything that closely resembles this question.

Comment: So if we normally create 3 threads then they won't run in parallel but if we submit a task to executor service having 3 threads, then these 3 threads will execute the task in parallel right?

Comment: Yes, different threads will run in parallel. Whether they run via ExecutorService or not is irrelevant. How the threads are managed will depend on your running environment. I read your discussion with @pablochan. There should be nothing more that I can add D:

Answer (score 0):

Executor service is a sophisticated thread pool and allow execute several independent tasks in background.

If they are processed in parallel or not, depends on how many cpu available units you have in your machine, and the exact use of those cpu is out of programmer control.